# Show $u$ satisfy poisson equation

Tags: analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f\in \mathcal S(\mathbb R^n),n\geq 3$. How can I show that $$u(x)=C_n\int_{\mathbb R^n}|x-y|^{2-n}f(y)dy$$
where $C_n$ is a suitable constant solve Poisson equation ? i.e. $$\Delta u=f.$$

The big problem is to permute $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_i}$ and the integral, but also if I can, I still have the fact that $|x-y|^{2-n}$ is not differentiable (and also not defined) when $y=x$.

Comment: Are you trying to argue that it is a classical solution? It is often easier to argue that it is a weak solution and then justify the regularity after the fact.

Comment: Well, an instant idea is to use the symmetric property of convolutions, so that you can move over the derivatives on $f$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is proved in Evans's PDE book, where the necessity of $n>2$ is also well explained.

Proof (Evans; I adapt.): The right-hand side of your formula provides a solution to $$\Delta u=f .$$ Because $f$ is Schwartz and

$$\int|x-y|^{2-n} \longrightarrow 0$$

outside large enough balls (note that this holds if $n>2$), we can see that the right hand side is in fact a bounded solution to $\Delta u=f$.

By uniqueness of bounded solutions (Liouville's Theorem) you can fix the constant so that $u$ is of the right hand side form.

About how you prove that RHS "is" indeed a solution, you have to prove that despite the discontinuity at $x=y$ the integral is continuously differentiable twice, and then calculate the Laplacian. You will then prove that it equals f. Fix an $x$, write the very definition of partial derivative as $h\longrightarrow 0$ of the difference quotient. In all other calculations, again work with fixed $x$.

Hope this helps. I know I did not present in the most clear way, but... Feel free to ask.

Comment: Idon't understand "since $f\in S(\mathbb R^n)$, $\int |x-y|^{2-n}\to 0$". First, which limit ? As $n\to \infty $ ? And why is it a consequence of $f$ in Schwartz ? Thanks,

Comment: I'm sorry. The second limit goes to zero regardless of $f$. Not when n goes to infinity. n is fixed once and for all, its dimension in $R^n$. What is going to zero is the integral of $\Phi (x-y)$ when integrated over regions outside large balls. That is saying that the integral at infinite edges are small. Notice that I said "Because ff is Schwartz and..." So, "and" does not mean I conclude what follows from what came before.